# How to link against Windows system libraries with CMake?

Tags: windows, dll, linker, cmake

I am building a simple Windows application that needs to link against gdiplus and winmm.
Previously I was using

```
find_library(GDIPLUS gdiplus)
target_link_libraries(target ${GDIPLUS})
```

but CMake does not find the library when using the Visual Studio 2015 target with the Visual C++ Build Tools. According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564193/cmake-how-to-link-executable-to-winmm-imm32-version-on-windows-with-visual-stu) I should probably drop the `find_library` and just use

```
target_link_libraries(target gdiplus.lib)
```

but I'm not sure if this will only work for Visual Studio or for example also with Cygwin.
So what is the correct (or best) way to link against Windows system libraries from CMake?

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking to link with Rpcrt4.lib and this worked on windows

```
target_link_libraries(${"LIB_NAME"} rpcrt4.lib)
```